# Why does my browser save my password as `f5-sso-token`?

Tags: browser, password-management

My university's email service runs on Outlook Web App. When I visit `outlook.umontreal.ca` I am redirected to a login page, and after logging in, both Firefox and Chrome offer to remember my password but save it as `f5-sso-token` instead of my actual password.

The login prompt used to be native to Outlook Web App, but the university recently replaced it with its standard authentication page. I don't think this is causing my problem because other online services provided by my university use the same login page and the issue doesn't come up.

A Google search for `f5-sso-token` only yields two results. One is a [forum thread](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=el&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.adslgr.com%2Fforum%2Farchive%2Findex.php%2Ft-843880.html) where the OP complains about Chrome and IE saving that same password. Someone brought up Chrome Sync, but the sync service is disabled in both Firefox and Chrome.

A few services that use the same login page: [StudiUM](https://studium.umontreal.ca/) / [Synchro](https://academique-dmz.synchro.umontreal.ca/) / [Portail](https://www.portail.umontreal.ca/)

I'm using Firefox 36.0 and Chrome 40.0.2214.115 m on Windows 7, but I'm pretty sure this already occurred on previous versions. I haven't tried to replicate the issue on IE.

Comment: "SSO" implies that they are using Single Sign-On i.e. the service will authenticate you against Active Directory or Kerberos or some such instead of actually validating your password directly.

Comment: @tripleee OK, then the problem must be on Outlook Web App's end. I'll see if I can edit my password as a temporary solution.